# Why cannot I assign a value to the object reference being returned by a method?

Tags: java, oop, reference, variable-assignment

I have a function which returns a reference to an object. Why cannot I assign this returned reference to point to another object? The reference being returned by the function is not final , hence I should be allowed to change it's value to point to another object.

```
class TestClass3 {
    public TestClass3 hello() {
        TestClass3 t = new TestClass3();
        return t;
    }
}

class TestClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass3 obj = new TestClass3();

        // The below line of code gives an error
        obj.hello() = null; 
    }
}
```

I expect that the reference returned by calling the hello() method should be assigned null value.

Comment: You are trying to set a method to a value. This isnt possible and doesnt make sence.

Comment: Your expected result makes no sense to me. _You_ don't actually manipulate an object in memory when doing `someVar = null`, the object stays where it is and the Garbage Collector will clean it up. What's why it makes no sense to "set a reference to null", Java doesn't provide such functionalities. You can set a variable to null to not use a certain reference anymore.

Comment: @Tom Yes it does throw an error, already by the compiler. Test it. The problem is: You can only assign values to variables. He wants to assign a value to a value (the reference counts a value, it isn't a variable) and that isn't possible

Comment: @Patrick Where did I claim it doesn't raise a compiler error? And I don't need to test it, I know how Java works. Also thanks for explaining to me what I already explained to OP.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to assign `obj.hello()` to a variable, which you can then set to `null` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the method to a value, this isn't possible and doesn't make any sense, if you think about it. If you want to save the reference returned by `obj.hello()`, write

```
TestClass3 obj2 = obj.hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code when you write `obj.hello()`, it only call the method `hello`. It doesn't assign the return of `hello` to any variable. So no variable is actually holding the return value of the method `hello`. While you can assign null value to same variable. That's why it's not a valid syntax.

Valid syntax should be like:

```
TestClass3 value = obj.hello();
value = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, it's because Java doesn't allow it while there are languages that do (e.g Python). In Java you cannot [monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) existing code.

Why? Well, Java wasn't born as a functional language, so while considerable for  function references was added in Java 8, they're still not first class citizens. So you cannot assign a new value to a method of a class like you can with a field of that class.

However, since you can assign values to fields, you could do something like this:

```
class TestClass3 {

    public Supplier<TestClass3> hello;

    public TestClass3() {
        this.hello = this::hello;
    }

    public TestClass3 hello() {
        TestClass3 t = new TestClass3();
        return t;
    }
}

class TestClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass3 obj = new TestClass3();
        obj.hello.get(); // calls hello()
        obj.hello = null; // now works
    }
}
```

Here I define a member named `hello` in `TestClass3`. It's of type `Supplier<TestClass3>`, and it just so happens that `public TestClass3 hello()` is of the same type. Hence, in the constructor of `TestClass3` I can do this: `this.hello = this::hello;`.

Now we have a reference to `hello()` as a **field**, which means that we can invoke the function using that field, or even change the field's value:

```
obj.hello.get();
obj.hello = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

*obj.hello()* is an **object's behavior**, not a reference, only reference can be set to null.

> About null:

- ***null*** is just a **reference value**.
- reference is a variable that has a name and can be used to **access an object** by referring to the memory address where it is located.

> About Object:

All objects have three essential features:

- state
- **behavior**
- identity